# Our cat frayed the carpet in bedroom corner by the door

Tags: carpet

Another cat Banned from the bedroom. Our cat frayed the carpet in the corner by the door.  The damage is small, approximately 1"X1". I saved the carpet fibers, Can this be fixed easily?

Comment: So you have a frayed-y-cat.

Comment: Seriously though, the fix will depend on the type of carpet and type of damage. Pictures?

Comment: Two easy fixes is to cut a similar size section from a closet/under bed or dresser, or place something like small table over it.  Replacing the fibers probably not easy.

Comment: I'm a frayed reweaving is impractical, but are there any carpet remnants left from installation? If inserting a plug from it, be careful to align grain. Any subtle color difference (new vs. old) will disappear with time.

Comment: The only solution I've found short of a patch is to trim the frayed strands back to carpet height and hope the carpet will squash down enough to fill in the gap. Sometimes you can get away with that.